# Find second derivative of $y=Ae^{-{2iy}}\sin ^2 x$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> Find the second derivative of $y=Ae^{-{2iy}}\sin ^2 x$

Finding the second derivative by first separating $y'$ to lhs is very tedious. Is there a better method for finding the double derivative?

Comment: Is here $$y=y(x)$$?

Comment: yes............

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$y=Ae^{-{2iy}}\sin ^2 x$$
Taking logarithm we have, 
$$\log y=\log A~-~{2iy}~+~2\log |\sin x|$$
Differentiating, $$\frac{1}{y}y'=0~-~2iy'~+~2~\cot x$$
$$\implies \left(\frac{1}{y}~+~2i\right)y'=2~\cot x$$
Again differentiating $$-\frac{y'^2}{y^2}~+\frac{y''}{y}~+~2iy''=-2~\csc^2 x$$
$$\implies \left(\frac{1}{y}~+~2i\right)y''=\frac{y'^2}{y^2}-2~\csc^2 x$$

Comment: What if $\sin{(x)}\lt0$? You cannot write $$\ln{(\sin^2{(x)})}=2\ln{(\sin{(x)})}$$

Comment: It is $$\sin^2(x)\geq 0$$

Comment: It must be $$2\log|\sin(x)|$$

Comment: Hello Mr. Down-voter, can you specify why you gave the downvote ? Please